# Proof verification on differentiability of multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R^3\to \mathbb{R}}$ be define as

$$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if }(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{Q^3} \\
 \sin(xyz) &\text{else}
\end{cases}$$

show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0,0)$ and not differentiable at $(1,1,\pi)$

what I did:

Let $ g: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be define as $g(x,y,z)=xyz\ $ then $g$ is a polynomial hence differentiable in $\mathbb{R^3}\ $and let $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\ $ be define as

$h(t)=\begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if } t\in \mathbb{Q} \\
 \sin(t) &\text{else}
\end{cases}$

now $f = h \circ g\ $ and now if we will show that $h$ is differentiable at $0$ we will get from the chain rule that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0,0).\ $ let $h_{1},h_{2} :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\ $ be $h_{1} = 0 $ and $h_{2} = \sin(t)$

now $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{h_{1}(t)}{t}=0\ $ and $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{h_{2}(t)}{t} =0\ $ Let $\epsilon >0 $ there exists $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2} > 0\ $ such that if $ |t|<\lambda_{1}$ then $|\frac{h_{1}(t)}{t}|<\epsilon$ and if $|t|<\lambda_{2}$ then $|\frac{h_{2}(t)}{t}|<\epsilon$ so let $\lambda = \min(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$. $\forall t$ such that $|t|<\lambda$ we have $|\frac{h(t)-h(0)}{t}|= |\frac{h(t)}{t}|<\epsilon$ hence $h$ is differentiable at $0$ and we are finish.

to show that $f$ is not differentiable at $(1,1,\pi)$ I will show that $f$ is not even continous at that point. for every ball center at $(1,1,\pi)$ there is rationals points and irationals points. so let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ now $\forall \lambda >0$ there exists a rational point $(x,y,z) \in B((1, 1, \pi), \lambda)$ and we have $|f(x,y,z)-f(1,1,\pi)|=|0-(-1)|=1> \epsilon\ $ so $f$ is not continous at $(1,1,\pi)$ so can't be differentiable there.

Is my proof ok?

edit: As jan has pointed out the solution above is not correct I will add another solution I have in mind.

We will use the definition of the deriative: $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{|f(x,y,z)-f(0,0,0)-(0,0,0) \cdot (x,y,z)|}{|(x,y,z)|}= \lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{|f(x,y,z)|}{|(x,y,z)|}\leq \lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}\frac{|\sin(xyz)|}{|(x,y,z)|}\leq \lim_{(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)}|xyz|=0$$
so by the definition of diffrentiablity f is differentiable at $(0,0,0)$ as desired.

For the point $a=(1,1,\pi)$ lets look at $$g(t)=f(a+(0,0,1)t)=f(1,1,\pi +t)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } t+\pi \in \mathbb{Q} \\
-\sin(t) & \text{if } t+\pi \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$
Define $A=\{r-\pi | r \in \mathbb{Q}\}, B=\{s-\pi | s \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\}\ $ so we have $$ \lim_{{t \to 0, \, t \in A}}\frac{g(t)}{t}=0 \neq -1 = \lim_{{t \to 0, \, t \in B}}\frac{g(t)}{t}$$ which means the directional deriative at the point $a$ in the direction of $(0,0,1)$ does not exists so the deriative at the point $a$ does not exists as desired.

and if I want to find all the points where the function are continous and differentiable how can I work that out? do I need to first have an intuition about the points that this true for them and after that try to show that indeed the function is continous and differentiable at those points and not continous and differentiable at another points or there is more direct way without an intuition?

Comment: Note $f(1,1,\pi)=0$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} h_2(t)\neq 0$. In fact $f$ is continuous at $(1,1,\pi)$. Your approach using the chain rule seems like a good idea though (even though I haven’t given it too much thought yet).

Comment: you right I made a mistake there, I will edit and add another solution I think is correct. thank you

Comment: I didn’t notice this earlier, but $f\neq h \circ g$ since $f(1,\sqrt2,\sqrt2)=\sin(2)\neq 0 = h\circ g(1,\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$. Edit: I see you’ve just edited your post I’ll look into it.

Comment: Your proof is almost correct, but there are two issues. Firstly, it’s unconventional to write inequalities between limits when you don’t know if they exist yet. That’s why it’s better to formulate your staps omitting the limit symbol until the very last step. Also, although the limit is indeed $0$, your last inequality to justify this is incorrect. The rest of the proof looks okay to me!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see why thats not correct . can I say $|x| = \sqrt{|x|^2} \leq \sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2 + |z|^2}$ which means that $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt(|x|^2 + |y|^2 + |z|^2)} \leq 1$ so we can multiply both sides by the positive number $|yz|$ and get $\frac{|xyz|}{\sqrt(|x|^2 + |y|^2 + |z|^2)} \leq |yz|$ and this is approaches 0 as $(x,y,z)$ approaches $0$ . does this look valid?

Comment: Yes, nicely done!